# Azure Logic App: RequestEntityTooLarge error with the FTP connector

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

First, please note I would like to be notified each time a new file comes in a remote FTp site, so I used the "When a file is added or modified" trigger. I do not need to get the file content but the trigger fails with the following:
"File size '58500725' exceeds maximum value '52428800'."
So, if the file on the FTP site is larger than 50 Mb, the trigger fails.
I understand there are [limitations](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-limits-and-config/) in Logic App but why this trigger tries to get the content of the file? It's name is "When a file is added or modified", I do not need more than that.
Any idea to implement this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is currently a gap in the functionality of the trigger (the content of the new/updated files is always fetched), and there is no workaround I can think of. May be a good idea to submit this requirement via https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. I already added https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/16801645-ftp-trigger-when-a-file-is-added-or-modified-sho yesterday.
Side note : it seems the Logic App source code is not open-source. If it was, I should be able to easily create my own FTP trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This is a technical limitation but the Logic Apps Team is now reviewing it.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there an option in the designer to specify "Do not use file contents"? That removes the 50MB limit from the triggering mechanism. However, in this case you can't use the content related fields in the action step.